# Tortoise HG (mercurial) notification of pushed changes

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Is there any option or extension/tool to inform you if someone else has pushed changes to a central mercurial server?  I often find that someone has pushed changes for a bug fix but I don't know until I manually check and that's getting old really fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could configure the [notify extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/NotifyExtension) on the central server to send out an email when changesets are pushed to it. If you're looking for a client-side solution and you are using Windows, you could try [HgAssist](https://bitbucket.org/zerkms/hgassist/wiki/Home).